# What is the purpose of onGetRoot() and onLoadChildren() in MediaBrowserServiceCompat?

Tags: android, android-mediasession, mediabrowserservicecompat

I am a beginner in Android Development trying to create a media player with the implementation of `MediaBrowser` and `MediaSession`.

I am confused with the function of `onGetRoot()` and `onLoadChildren()`.

1. My first question is in `layman's term` what is the purpose of these two methods.
2. What is the root they are pertaining in `onGetRoot()`? What I have in mind is, it is the root of the directory, am I correct?
3. What is the children pertaining in `onLoadChildren()`? what I have in mind is the list of music in the root, am I correct?
4. Will this `onLoadchildren()` return the actual playlist?

Comment: Are you trying to expose a library of media files from your app to other apps?

Comment: No, just locally. But I want to just try this `MediaBrowserServiceCompat` implementation.

Comment: try these https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice.html

Comment: and here https://github.com/googlesamples/android-MediaBrowserService

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Reference: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-app/building-a-mediabrowserservice

In order to understand this, it is important to have a clear understanding of what a `MediaItem` represents.
In the reference the following statement is provided "Your service is responsible for associating the ID with the appropriate menu node or content item."
You need to use the MediaItem class to define a hierarchy of items (PLAYABLE or BROWSEABLE). An example would be

root (Not a media item, but can be subscribed to return the highest level fo Media items)
->
songs(browseable)
albums (browseable)
artists (browseable)

the albums MediaItem, if subscribed to, would return something like
->
album1 (browseable)
album2 (browseable)

and in your album1 you would have your playable MP3s e.g.
->
song1.mp3 (playable)
song2.mp3 (playable)

For all browseable MediaItems we can choose to "subscribe" to them to get all of the child nodes; which helps when we one to dynamically build our UI.

Relating this concept to the software architecture, you need to think about what is going to access `onGetRoot` and `onLoadChildren`. They are part of a **MediaBrowserService**, therefore the functions will be interacted by a **MediaBrowser**.

1) `onGetRoot()` is called to gain **the authority** to access the Media that the `MediaBrowserService` provides. It will return a "root ID" which can be subscribed to and return the MediaItems at the highest level of your hierarchy. I.e. in the above example subscribing to the root node would return Songs, Albums and Artists.

`onLoadChildren()` is therefore called when we choose to subscribe to MediaItems to get their children nodes.

2) This does not relate to the root directory but rather a "root ID" used to subscribe to the top (root) level of your self defined hierarchy

3) `OnLoadChildren` is called by the subscribe method of the MediaBrowser and will return all child MediaItems (browseable or playable).

4) `OnLoadChildren` can return a playlist if you wish. To do so define a mediaItem "playlist name" which can be browseable and it will return the MediaItems in that playlist.

Comment: Very clearly described, better than the Android doc do it imo. Although they explained the methods it wasn't clear to me how client and service interacted via the subscribe, from the docs. This makes it crystal clear. Thanks